# Angular JS ngclick in ngrepeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a ng-click on a button in ng-repeat, however the function isn't ever called?
Can someone tell me why?

```
<div ng-repeat="data in exploreResults">
    <button type="button" ng-click="showMap(data, exploreResults)" class="showMapExploreButton">{{data.name}}</button>
    <p>Address: {{data.address}}<br>
    Rating: {{data.rating == 0 ? 'No rating available' : data.rating}} <br>
    Coordinates: {{data.coordinates.latitude}}, {{data.coordinates.longitude}}</p>
    <div ng-show=data.showMap id="map-canvas-explore" style="float:right; height: 20%; width: 50%; padding-right:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

The java script is the following:

```
<script>
function showMap(data, all) {
    all.forEach(function(entry) {
            entry.showMap = false;
    });
    data.showMap = true;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    //initialize map
    function initializeMap() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coordinates.latitude, data.coordinates.longitude);
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas-explore');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latLng, 
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Destination'
        });
    }
    initializeMap();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
}
</script>
```

Thanks for any help;)

Comment: if you want to make it working on `ng-click` then this function `showMap` should be in controller scope

Comment: If you accept my opinion, there's code for a directive here, because you're dealing with DOM manipulation while creating a map. I suggest to you the `Angular UI Maps` to handle the map for you, its more intuitive if you aren't inside enough of Angular.js world. http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Answer (score 0):

Update:- Description about the answer:- You haven't bound `showMap()`   function on the scope. Bind it with `$scope.showMap = function(data, all){...}` as shown below

```
  <script>
    $scope.showMap = function(data, all) {
        all.forEach(function(entry) {
                entry.showMap = false;
        });
        data.showMap = true;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //initialize map
        function initializeMap() {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coordinates.latitude, data.coordinates.longitude);
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas-explore');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng, 
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Destination'
            });
        }
        initializeMap();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You are missing something like, `$scope.exploreResults= (//some data here)` I mean `exploreResults` is not bound to the scope either. How are u getting this `exploreResults` data?

Comment: explore results is from the scope - everything works fine except for the onclick

Comment: hey Oliver, shouldn't all this javaScript code be in controller? I dont see the controller. Can you provide the full controller code please. that would help debug it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The function call in the ng-click directive needs to reference a function on the scope, in the same way that exploreResults should be a scope variable. That is

```
$scope.showMap = function(data, all) {
    all.forEach(function(entry) {
        entry.showMap = false;
    });
    data.showMap = true;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    //initialize map
    function initializeMap() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coordinates.latitude, data.coordinates.longitude);
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas-explore');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latLng, 
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Destination'
        });
    }
    initializeMap();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
}
```

within the relevant controller.